# xcode is not showing the output

Tags: c++, xcode

I tried several time to find where is the problem, but I can not find any thing.So, could anyone help me to find the problem and why I can not see a result?

It might seem stupid question, but I new to programming world :)

**This is my code :**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// There is the declraction of all functions

float max();
float min();


// This is the main program

int main ( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    // Here you can find max
    max(504.50,70.33);

    // Here you can find min
    min(55.77, 80.12);
    return 0;
}


// This is the max function

int max(float a, float b){

    float theMax;
    if (a>b) {
        theMax = a;
        cout <<theMax ;
    }
    else{
        theMax = b;
        cout << b;
    }
    return theMax;
}

// This is the min function

int min( float c, float d){

    float theMin;
    if (c >d ) {
        theMin =c;
        cout << theMin;
    }
    else {
        theMin =d;
        cout << theMin;
    }
    return theMin;
}
```

Comment: Consider using better names for max and min and/or get rid of `using namespace std;` - also your prototypes are invalid. You are most likely just calling std::max and std::min instead of your own functions.

Comment: I did what you said, but It did not work

Comment: Edit your question to include the latest version of your code - you probably missed something.

Comment: I find the problem, It was in declaration of the functions and I also change the mix and min name to something else. Thank you  (Paul R) for your help and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `std::max` and `std::min`. That's because you wrote `using namespace std`, and did not declare your own `min` and `max` prior to using them. (You did declare two other `min` and `max`  functions, but those take zero arguments, not two). So, when the compiler sees `max(504.50,70.33);` the only candidate is `std::max`.

Comment: yes the problem was in the declaration. It works now. Thank you 

(MSalters)

Answer (score 1):

You declare these overloads:

```
float max();
float min();
```

which are functions that take no arguments and return `float`.

You're calling

```
max(504.50,70.33);
```

and

```
min(55.77, 80.12);
```

which are functions that takes two `double`s and may or may not return anything.
These match `std::max` and `std::min`, not the prototypes you declared.

You then define

```
int min( float c, float d){
```

which also doesn't match the prototypes you declared.
In other words, these functions are unknown in `main`, and the functions that are actually called are `std::min` and `std::max`.

Don't use `using namespace std;` - what you save in typing is lost in clarity and debugging.

You should also rename the functions - it's not a good idea to reuse standard library names.